# Characters encoding in httpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, httpresponse

I'm coding a Swedish website. When there is an error with connection with server I'm catching and error 500 adding information about it and send it to web page. This information is send as response for request and contain Swedish characters (ö).

Firstly message was containing: Status error and ReasonPhrase (with Swedish characters). The problem is that when I'm testing this after deploy ReasonPhrase comes without Swedish characters(Ã¶). When I'm testing it locally ReasonPhrase comes with correct symbols on each browser.

I have tried to add message as a value of Header. Locally when I test it on Chrome, Firefox message comes without Swedish characters, but it is correct on IE. I have tried to add different Headers: Content-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Language. I have tried UTF-8 as well as ISO-8859-1. Haven't helped.

When I added this message to Response Body it comes correctly(with Swedish characters) to Chrome and Firefox but not to IE.

May it be related with server settings? Or maybe I have missed something. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using character encoding i.e. &x00f6; for your particular character seeing as the message is for display in a web-browser, it's likely to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, works in same way as i wrote it like normal letter(ö).